# geth + truffle-hd-wallet accounts not listed properly

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, hd-wallets

I have setup a latest single node geth for my learning. I am also using truffle-hd-wallet in my app. While in my app i do not get the correct coinbase account on using 'web3.eth.getCoinbase()'; the same command in the geth cli gives me correct coinbase account.

In my app 'web3.eth.getCoinbase()' retunrs me the first account created by truffle-hd-wallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use truffle-hdwallet-provider, it sets coinbase to first account of HD wallet. thats why you get different results.

You can view code here:
https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider/blob/master/index.js

```
 Line 5: var HookedSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js');

 Line 28: this.engine.addProvider(new HookedSubprovider({
 Line 29:   getAccounts: function(cb) { cb(null, tmp_accounts) },
```

And, https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine/blob/master/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js

```
Line 92: case 'eth_coinbase':
Line 93:       // process normally
Line 94:       self.getAccounts(function(err, accounts){
Line 95:         if (err) return end(err)
Line 96:         let result = accounts[0] || null
Line 97:         end(null, result)
Line 98:       })
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a wallet that can also manage accounts created in the geth node along with external ones?

Comment: why would you want that? Concept of coinbase account is used primarily when you are mining, the mining rewards always goes to coinbase account.

Comment: no specific usecase..but is it not good a single wallet manages all the accounts?

Comment: yes, thats what is happening here, hd wallet is only managing accounts in its hd path, not the local geth  accounts.